# Directories are missing from Azure Portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal

I've been experiencing this for month already.

I have different subscriptions and I created 3-4 Azure B2C directories. Subscriptions are from different clients. Azure B2C directories are used for apps for those clients. But some B2C directories are used for testing locally on my machine and also in VSTS (CI/CD).

The problem is when I log in to Azure Portal I don't see all of them (on the top right corner, in user email dropdown). Most of the time it works, but there are many times when I log in and see just 2 directories in that dropdown. I sign out, sign in again - and sometimes it solves the problem, sometimes I get only one directory. So I sign out again, tried different browsers. I even had to change my service provider. And it helped for a while but today I got this again.

It's very inconsistent and VERY annoying.

Addition:

I must add that my internet connection is 4G (LTE). So I don't have a static IP. I don't know if that have any impact but it seems it does. I had originally this problem with one 4G (LTE) internet provider, so I switched to another. And I hadn't had the problem for about 2 or 3 weeks. And now I have it again.

Comment: Do you ever notice if the directories load after a few mins? Wondering if they are being slow to load or if they are just not loading at all

Comment: They are not loading at all. But again, not always. It's like a lottery.

Comment: I just had this again. I waited for ~5 min and didn't get my directories. I noticed it gets stuck for ~1min at this url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3a%2f%2fmanagement.core.windows.net%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=user_impersonation+openid&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3blahblah&client_id=guid&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fportal.azure.com%2fsignin%2findex%2f%3fsignIn%3d1&site_id=501430&client-request-id=45d3edda-cfe5-48ea-a0c5-f5313b5b615f&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=1.0.40306.1554&sso_nonce=blahblah

Comment: damn, now it stuck at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/federation/oauth2

Comment: this one https://portal.azure.com/signin/index/?signIn=1 just took 61 sec

Comment: can you send an email to AzCommunity@Microsoft.com with your subscription ID. I can take a look. Thanks, Micah

Comment: Sent with the topic 'Regarding my question on SO'. Please do something about it

Comment: Azure guys, please add a bullet proof way of switching directories in the Portal! The directories exist it's just the portal does not show them in the menu! I can't work right now because of this issue!

Comment: here's what I get from C# code trying to access the directory that's mine but missing:

```
Error Calling the Graph API: 
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Resource '06595b7a-682e-459b-9080-1fdafe23dfcd' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It just loaded all directories for a min, I managed to add 2 of them to Favorites. Now they disappeared again (in 3 min). And if I go to a stored link I get 
>> Dashboard not found
We could not load the dashboard named 'private/8c92286d-4471-47fd-a88c-ec576425a013'. Refresh the portal to try again.

Nice work :(

Comment: I am sure once the ticket you submitted has been picked up the engineer will be able to better tell us what is happening. I am still tracking that ticket. Appreciate the patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, there was a problem with Azure Portal and Microsoft took some time to diagnose and fix it. Now it works.